# Mockery and Laravel testing: Call to a member function __call() on a non-object

Tags: php, unit-testing, laravel-4, phpunit

i am trying to run tests in laravel generated with https://github.com/JeffreyWay/Laravel-4-Generators

My testcase file is like this: http://pastebin.com/U9zfmyM6

The controller file: http://pastebin.com/aiYZa6dA

The controller generated test file is like this: http://pastebin.com/nh9Bv9ht

I run phpunit with `vendor/bin/phpunit` and i get this:

```
tom@debian:~/public_html/madserver-laravel$ vendor/bin/phpunit 
PHPUnit 3.7.29 by Sebastian Bergmann.

Configuration read from /home/tom/public_html/madserver-laravel/phpunit.xml

...PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function __call() on a non-object in /home/tom/public_html/madserver-laravel/vendor/mockery/mockery/library/Mockery/Loader/EvalLoader.php(16) : eval()'d code on line 350
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /home/tom/public_html/madserver-laravel/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/composer/bin/phpunit:0
PHP   2. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command::main() /home/tom/public_html/madserver-laravel/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/composer/bin/phpunit:63
PHP   3. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command->run() /home/tom/public_html/madserver-laravel/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/PHPUnit/TextUI/Command.php:129
PHP   4. PHPUnit_TextUI_TestRunner->doRun() /home/tom/public_html/madserver-laravel/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/PHPUnit/TextUI/Command.php:176
PHP   5. PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite->run() /home/tom/public_html/madserver-laravel/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/PHPUnit/TextUI/TestRunner.php:349
PHP   6. PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite->run() /home/tom/public_html/madserver-laravel/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/PHPUnit/Framework/TestSuite.php:705
PHP   7. PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite->runTest() /home/tom/public_html/madserver-laravel/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/PHPUnit/Framework/TestSuite.php:745
PHP   8. PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase->run() /home/tom/public_html/madserver-laravel/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/PHPUnit/Framework/TestSuite.php:775
PHP   9. PHPUnit_Framework_TestResult->run() /home/tom/public_html/madserver-laravel/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/PHPUnit/Framework/TestCase.php:783
PHP  10. PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase->runBare() /home/tom/public_html/madserver-laravel/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/PHPUnit/Framework/TestResult.php:648
PHP  11. PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase->runTest() /home/tom/public_html/madserver-laravel/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/PHPUnit/Framework/TestCase.php:838
PHP  12. ReflectionMethod->invokeArgs() /home/tom/public_html/madserver-laravel/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/PHPUnit/Framework/TestCase.php:983
PHP  13. BannersTest->testStore() /home/tom/public_html/madserver-laravel/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/PHPUnit/Framework/TestCase.php:983
PHP  14. Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase->call() /home/tom/public_html/madserver-laravel/app/tests/controllers/BannersTest.php:47
PHP  15. call_user_func_array() /home/tom/public_html/madserver-laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/TestCase.php:74
PHP  16. Symfony\Component\BrowserKit\Client->request() /home/tom/public_html/madserver-laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/TestCase.php:74
PHP  17. Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Client->doRequest() /home/tom/public_html/madserver-laravel/vendor/symfony/browser-kit/Symfony/Component/BrowserKit/Client.php:319
PHP  18. Illuminate\Foundation\Application->handle() /home/tom/public_html/madserver-laravel/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Client.php:81
PHP  19. Illuminate\Foundation\Application->dispatch() /home/tom/public_html/madserver-laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php:691
PHP  20. Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatch() /home/tom/public_html/madserver-laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php:716
PHP  21. Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatchToRoute() /home/tom/public_html/madserver-laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php:939
PHP  22. Illuminate\Routing\Route->run() /home/tom/public_html/madserver-laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php:969
PHP  23. call_user_func_array() /home/tom/public_html/madserver-laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php:105
PHP  24. Illuminate\Routing\Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}() /home/tom/public_html/madserver-laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php:105
PHP  25. Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher->dispatch() /home/tom/public_html/madserver-laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php:905
PHP  26. Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher->call() /home/tom/public_html/madserver-laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php:62
PHP  27. Illuminate\Routing\Controller->callAction() /home/tom/public_html/madserver-laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php:93
PHP  28. call_user_func_array() /home/tom/public_html/madserver-laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Controller.php:194
PHP  29. BannersController->store() /home/tom/public_html/madserver-laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Controller.php:194
PHP  30. Mockery_0_Banner::create() /home/tom/public_html/madserver-laravel/app/controllers/BannersController.php:65
PHP  31. Mockery_0_Banner::__callStatic() /home/tom/public_html/madserver-laravel/vendor/mockery/mockery/library/Mockery/Loader/EvalLoader.php(16) : eval()'d code:946
tom@debian:~/public_html/madserver-laravel$
```

I have been serching so much and tested a lot of things to get this to work, but same result :(

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please include relevant parts of the source code here. Links may break in the future and this question would lack important information. See [ask] and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in help.

Answer (score 1):

For me this was resolved by moving

```
    $this->mock = m::mock('Eloquent', 'Models\Broadcasts\Voice\VoiceBroadcast')->shouldDeferMissing();
    $this->collection = m::mock('Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection')->shouldDeferMissing();
```

from `__construct()` to `setUp()`

Answer (score 0):

I was having this same problem.  I got the test to pass by changing `$this->mock = m::mock('Eloquent', 'Banner');` to `$this->mock = m::mock('Banner');`.

I'm not sure the issue or what I'm missing out on by taking out the `Eloquent` param, though.